# Using php how can I check if GZIP is turned on?

Tags: php, gzip

I am not asking for an online tool. I'm also not asking how to turn on or turn off gzip.

What I want to know, is how, within my php, that I can check to see if gzip will encode the current buffer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by `gzip will encode the current buffer` but i assume you mean "compress the output before sending it"

```
if(ini_get("zlib.output_compression")) {
    echo "On";
} else {
    echo "off";
}
```

---

Should you be talking about `ob_*` functions and output streams there is [`ob_get_status`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php) but afaik you can't check if that was started with `ob_gzhandler()` or not. Your application would have to track that. [But zlib compression is preferred anyways](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to know whether or not mod_deflate in Apache has been activated, there's no API in PHP to determine that. You could, obviously, use a shell command and parse the output, but it's probably not the preferred way. The question is though: why should PHP care if the output is gzipped?

Comment: Agreed. Aside from collecting statistics I don't see a reason PHP would need to know. `ob_gzhandler()` and `zlib.output_compression` automatically detect if the user agent supports gzipping and do or do not do the gzipping accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

probably like so:

```
ini_get('zlib_output_compression');
```

(for the manual see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php )