# How to in PHP is GZIP is enabled?

Tags: php, apache, gzip, litespeed

I need to run some function but only if GZIP is enabled on server (Apache or LiteSpeed). How can I detect this?

I've tried:

```
if(ini_get("zlib.output_compression")) {
    echo "On";
} else {
    echo "off";
}
```

and I found it here [Using php how can I check if GZIP is turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592988/using-php-how-can-i-check-if-gzip-is-turned-on)

I need this because I want to create function that add GZIP rules to .htaccess but only if GZIP is not active by default.

Comment: Checking `zlib.output_compression` would only tell you, if PHP itself was configured to compress any output it creates, but that won't tell you if compression was enabled on the web server level.